# How to call different handlers from gcp app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

My code is given below.
I am expecting `*.appspot.com/main` should give "Inside main" and `*.appspot.com/run` should give "Inside run".
Though */run is working fine, but */main is giving `Page Not Found` error.

main.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/main")
def not_home():
    return "Inside main - Hello"
```

run.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/run")
def home():
    return "Inside run - Hello"
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python
env: flex
service: default
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 run:app
instance_class: F2
runtime_config:
    python_version: 3.7
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 5
  disk_size_gb: 10
handlers:
- url: /main
  script: main.py
- url: /run
  script: run.py
automatic_scaling:
  max_num_instances: 3
  min_num_instances: 1
```

Please help.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up the App Engine Standard(ex. [handlers & scaling elements](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref)) and Flexible([ex. resources](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml)) `app.yaml` configuration. Even it's not giving you any error, it's just being ignored. You should choose what App Engine environment you are going to use, please visit this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) it can help you to decide.

Your goal will run with the example App Engine Flexible setup below that has all function in one entry:

**`run.py:`**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

@app.route("/run")
def home():
    return "Inside run - Hello"

@app.route("/main")
def not_home():
    return "Inside main - Hello"
```

**`app.yaml`**

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 run:app
runtime_config:
    python_version: 3.7
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```